# Add multiple styling class to object on React Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have JSX like this:

```
 <span className="btn-pause btn"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span>
```

Now I want to change the color of this button:

```
const styles = {
   btncolor:{
      backgroundColor:"#0E122D"
   }
}
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles)
```

How should I add this style to `className` with normal other class?

```
 <span className="btn-pause btn {{classes.btncolor}}"><i className="fa fa-pause"></i></span>
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: `"btn-pause btn {{classes.btncolor}}"` is just a _string_, one that literally includes the "class" `{{classes.btncolor}}`. How would you normally interpolate a value into a string? If you do `className={...}` you can use whatever JavaScript you like to create the appropriate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding color variable under quotes. Here is corrected answer:

```js
<span className={`btn-pause btn ${classes.btncolor}`}>
  <i className="fa fa-pause"></i>
</span>
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**
For managing class assigning you can use library [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames). The way you use it in your case would be like this:

```js
import classnames from 'classnames';

....
<span className={classnames("btn-pause", "btn", classes.btncolor)>
  <i className="fa fa-pause"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you I can add the class with this solution.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.